# How to search with multiple entities in Axios Assyst?

Tags: rest, api, axios

I am using making two http calls to Assyst REST api to fetch Priority value and closure action value like as follows.

```
 > http://localhost:8989/assyst/assystGOLD/Priority?shortCode=%225%22&fields=name,shortCode&fmt=xml
 > http://localhost:8989/assyst/assystGOLD/ActionType?shortCode=%22closure%22&fmt=xml
```

Now I want to merge these two url's to work in a single call. So I made below URL, but no luck.

> http://localhost:8989/assyst/assystGOLD/ActionType?shortCode=%22closure%22&Priority?shortCode=%225%22&fields=name,shortCode&fmt=xml

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible I'm afraid. The REST API only works with a single resource (Priority and Action Type in your example) in each request. You need to  make two requests to get these two unrelated pieces of information.

Your example is using the legacy API's syntax. I recommend using the new REST API for new development - it is embedded within the main assyst Enterprise application and has much improved performance.

Paul